# PHP Переносит не на ту страницу

Tags: php, mysql, auth

При успешной попытке входа получаю ответ не перенос в дашборд, а перенос на не понятную страницу login.php в папке users.

Основной php:

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    include("includes/db.php");

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        header("Location: user/index.php");
        exit;
    }

    $error = "";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                header("Location: user/index.php");
                exit;
            } else {
                $error = "Invalid email or password.";
            }
        } else {
            $error = "Invalid email or password.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Кнопка входа:

```html
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Log In</button>
```

При успешной авторизации должен быть перенос в user/index.php, но переносит в user/login.php
[image]

form:

```html
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Log In</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Покажите тег `<form>`. Скорее всего у вас там указано `action='user/login.php'`

Comment: @SwaD указал в теме

Comment: у вас желаемая страница перехода для авторизованного пользователя user/index.php от корня сайта? Напишите header("Location: /user/index.php");